# Is there some trick to getting Whitebox GAT scripts to run the plugins?

Tags: whitebox-gat

I'm trying to get a small script to run using Whitebox's Scripter:

```
print("Running script")

# data path
whiteboxdp = "/Users/analytics/dem_catchment/sites/Southwold/whitebox_files/"

# set local working directory
pluginHost.setWorkingDirectory(whiteboxdp)

# Calculate dem fill
base_dem = whiteboxdp + "Southwold_lidar_dem_2m_full.dep"
filled_dem = whiteboxdp + "SW_filled.dep"
flatIncrement = "0.0001"
args = [base_dem, filled_dem, flatIncrement]

# does nothing that I can see, no processing or output
pluginHost.runPlugin("FillDepression", args, False, False)

print("Script finished")
```

When I execute/run the script I just instantly get:

```
Running script
Script finished
```

No errors or other warnings. No content generated.
I looked at the example by [John Lindsay](https://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/workflow-automation-in-whitebox-gat/) but I feel that I'm not using this correctly as it's not implementing any of the toolbox calls.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the Whiteboxdb path needs a Drive designation such as C:

Comment: Agree with ^ klewis. I'm actually surprised this isn't throwing some variety of file not found error. Is there a "debug mode" or "debug option" for the scripter where you can watch for errors or warnings? Optionally, you could try wrapping in a try catch and do a `print("error caught..")` instruction in the catch block.

Comment: This is running on a Mac so the pathnames are correct. I can get the script to list files fine using `os.listdir(whiteboxdp)`. The 'try - catch' suggestion won't work as no errors are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of these, pasting them right into the scripting window:

Mosiac with Feather

```
import os
try:
   separator = os.sep
   wd = pluginHost.getApplicationDirectory() + separator + "resources" + separator + "samples" + separator + "Vermont DEM" + separator
   pluginHost.setWorkingDirectory(wd)
   baseFile = wd + "Vermont DEM.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(baseFile)
   appendFile = wd + "hillshade.dep"
   pluginHost.returnData(appendFile)
   outputFile = wd + "output.dep"
   resamplingmethod = "nearest neighbour"
   matchHistograms = "true"
   args = [baseFile, appendFile, outputFile, resamplingmethod, matchHistograms, '4.0']
   pluginHost.runPlugin("MosaicWithFeathering", args, False)
except Exception, e:
   print e
   pluginHost.showFeedback("Error during script execution.")
finally:
    print "I'm done!"
```

Slope calc:

```
import os
try:
   separator = os.sep
   wd = pluginHost.getApplicationDirectory() + separator + "resources" + separator + "samples" + separator + "Vermont DEM" + separator
   pluginHost.setWorkingDirectory(wd)
   print(wd)
   basefile = wd + 'Vermont DEM.dep'
   pluginHost.returnData(basefile)
   outputFile = wd + "slope.dep"
   zFactor = "1.0"
   args = [basefile, outputFile, zFactor]
   pluginHost.runPlugin("Slope", args, False)
except Exception, e:
   print e
   pluginHost.showFeedback("Error during script execution.")
finally:
    print "I'm done!"
```